# LinkedIn login REST api: scope for getting email and profile picture

Tags: javascript, rest, linkedin-api

I am trying to authenticate the user via LinkedIn REST API.

Here is the URL

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=jjkk&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/auth/linkedincallback&state=987654378766&scope=r_basicprofile&&scope=r_emailaddress
```

On the successful authtoken creation I am using this endpoint to retrieve profile data from the API.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,picture-url,email-address,positions)?format=json
```

But the `email` and  profile-picture is missing from the response

Scopes I've added `r_basicprofile` and `r_emailaddress`

Comment: You are adding the scopes wrong, instead of supplying multiple parameters with the name `scope`, you need to supply _one_ containing a, quote docs, _“URL-encoded, space delimited list of member permissions”_

Comment: Like this way `scope=r_basicprofile r_emailaddress`

Comment: Yes, plus the URL-encoding of the space character.

Comment: Got it now the email is in the response but the profile-picture url is missing

Comment: Well then check if `r_basicprofile` is sufficient to access the user’s profile picture.

Comment: could you show more code and also show the permissions you have activated in the linkedin developer page.